# How do I change only one column of my table without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a php table where I want to be able to click on an edit button, the click should change the row, without refreshing the site.
I just don't know how to refresh only one row, I never used ajax before and while googling it, it seemed like it is the only way, can somebody please help me include ajax for me or explain what I can do?

The table selects all data from a mysql table then it displays them row by row and every row have a counterId so I know which row gets clicked.

Now I just need to be able to change the row if the edit button is clicked.

```
print '  <div class="tbl-content">';
print '    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
print '      <tbody>';
print '        <tr>';
print "          <td>$name</td>";
print "          <td>$amount</td>";
print "          <td>$country</td>";
print '          <td><input type="button" name="edit_'.$counter.'" value="Edit"></td>';
print '        </tr>';
print '      </tbody>';
print '    </table>';
print '  </div>';
```

If the Edit button is clicked it the rows name amount and country should change to text input rows and instead of an edit button there should be an delete and save button.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself to create this, there a already some examples of this on StackOverflow if you search a bit

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen well I didn't try much because I have no clue what to do?
Like I said I never used ajax and never made something like this, I have no clue what the next step is now, and while searching stackoverflow everything was way too advanced and I had no clue what I can from similar questions.

Comment: @Rajnish I don't want to buy an editor I want to learn it myself, I am just a studend and need this for my own projects

Comment: Alright then, See this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYoGKtdl7dQ